# Android Activity with VideoView starting twice Xamarin

Tags: android, android-fragments, video, xamarin, android-videoview

I have an Fragment which opens up a new activity in landscape mode which has a videoview to play a video. The problem s when the video is completed the activity with the video should finish and the control should automatically go back to the previous Fragment . Similar should be when the back button is pressed.

Currently, When the video gets completed it restarts and only when the second time it completes the control goes back to the previous Fragment . Same is with the back button press ie. I have o press the back button twice to finish the activity with the video.

Here is some code im doing:-

MainFragment

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
            mIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            mIntent.SetClass(this.Activity, typeof(VideoActivity));
            Activity.StartActivity(mIntent);
```

VideoActivity

```
 public class VideoActivity : Activity, Android.Media.MediaPlayer.IOnCompletionListener
    {
        private VideoView mVV;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.VideoLayout);

            // Create your application here
            int fileRes = 0;
            fileRes = Resource.Raw.trailer;


            mVV = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.myvideoview);
            mVV.SetOnCompletionListener(this);

            if(!mVV.IsPlaying)
            {
            if (!playFileRes(fileRes)) return;

            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            mc.SetAnchorView(mVV);
            mVV.SetMediaController(mc);
            }
            else
            {
                mVV.Suspend();
                Finish();

            }



        }

        private bool playFileRes(int fileRes)
        {
            if (fileRes == 0)
            {
                stopPlaying();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                mVV.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + fileRes.ToString()));
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void stopPlaying()
        {
            mVV.StopPlayback();
            this.Finish();
        }

        public void OnCompletion(Android.Media.MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            stopPlaying();

        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            mVV.Resume();
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            stopPlaying();
        }
        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            stopPlaying();
        }

    }
```

How do I solve this? Any help would be appreciated.